# echo pagenumber html php

Tags: php, html, css, echo

I am trying to echo pagenumbers in html. Below is the code. It does echo, 
but numbers are always on left side of the page. Then I created a `div` to 
center it, it did, but then all numbers are div. When user clicks on 
numbers, basically, div gets clicked. I want user to be able to click on
each page number with page numbers at the center of the page.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {  // print links for all pages
                echo '<a href="getjobs.php?function_Options[0]='.$q.'& function_Options[1]='.
                    $q1.'&state_Options[0]='.$qq.'&state_Options[1]='.
                    $qq1.'&state_Options[2]='.$qq2.'&state_Options[3]='.
                    $qq3.'&state_Options[4]='.$qq4.'&state_Options[5]='.
                    $qq5.'&page='.$i.'"';

                if ($i==$page)  echo " class='curPage'";

                echo " style='color: white; font-size: 20pt;'>".$i."</a> ";
            }; 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look up css text-alignment and or float. The numbers should be in a div container then the entire container can be aligned.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="pageNr">
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  // print links for all pages
   echo('<a href="getjobs.php?
   function_Options[0]='.$q.'& 
   function_Options[1]='.$q1.'&
   state_Options[0]='.$qq.'&
   state_Options[1]='.$qq1.'&
   state_Options[2]='.$qq2.'&
   state_Options[3]='.$qq3.'&
   state_Options[4]='.$qq4.'&
   state_Options[5]='.$qq5.'&
   page='.$i.'"');

   if ($i==$page)  echo " class='curPage'";
   echo " style='color: white; font-size: 20pt;'>".$i."</a> "; 
   }; 
?>
</div>
```

So you just need to make the width of your div like a couple of pixels and let it float right... this should work.

---

And just a little tip: best practice is that you don't use inline css...